# Add const when accessing member variable

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I need a transparent wrapper around a data structure to add some properties.
Easiest is something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper{
    T values;
}
```

Now I want to pass this to an accessor and keep constness. Base would be:

```
template<class T>
T& accVal(usigned idx, T* vals){ return vals[idx]; }
template<class T>
const T& accVal(usigned idx, const T* vals){ return vals[idx]; }

template<class T>
auto
acc(unsigned idx, T& data) -> decltype(accVal(idx, data.values))
{
    return accVal(idx, data.values);
}

//Example:
Wrapper<int*> intsWrapped;
cout << acc(1, intsWrapped);
```

This works only for non-pointers, say replace "T*" with a struct as the access to data.values discards the constness of data and I'd be able to manipulate it like:

```
void foo(const Wrapper<int*>& bar){ acc(1, bar) = 5; }
```

That is dangerous in my application.

So how can I preserve the constness? I tried something like this:

```
template< class T_Base, typename T_Mem >
struct GetConstCorrect
{
    template< typename T >
    struct AddConstVal: std::add_const<T>{};

    template< typename T >
    struct AddConstVal<T&>
    {
        using type = std::add_const_t<T> &;
    };

    template< typename T >
    struct AddConstVal<T*>
    {
        using type = std::add_const_t<T>*;
    };

    template< typename T >
    struct AddConstVal<T* const>
    {
        using type = std::add_const_t<T>* const;
    };

    template< typename T >
    struct AddConstVal<T*&>
    {
        using type = std::add_const_t<T>*&;
    };

    template< typename T >
    struct AddConstVal<T*const &>
    {
        using type = std::add_const_t<T>* const &;
    };

    using Base = T_Base;
    using Mem = T_Mem;

    static constexpr bool isConst = std::is_const<Base>::value;
    using type = std::conditional_t< isConst,
            typename AddConstVal<Mem>::type,
            Mem
            >;
};

template< class T_Base, typename T_Mem >
using GetConstCorrect_t = typename GetConstCorrect< T_Base, T_Mem >::type;

template< class T_Base, typename T_Mem >
GetConstCorrect_t< T_Base, T_Mem& >
getConstCorrect(T_Mem& mem)
{
    return const_cast<GetConstCorrect_t< T_Base, T_Mem& >>(mem);
}
```

And access data.values by getConstCorrect(data.values), but this still seems error prone. (E.g. a multipointer like int** would become int*const* not int const**)

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until anyone comes up with a better solution, I think this one is the answer:
Use AddConstVal as a recursive metafunction which removes all modifiers one by one, calls itself and readds the modifier.

```
template< typename T >
struct AddConstVal: std::add_const<T>{};

template< typename T >
using AddConstVal_t = typename AddConstVal<T>::type;

template< typename T >
struct AddConstVal<T&>
{
    using type = AddConstVal_t<T>&;
};

template< typename T >
struct AddConstVal<T*>
{
    using type = AddConstVal_t<T>*;
};

template< typename T >
struct AddConstVal<T const>
{
    using type = AddConstVal_t<T> const;
};

template< typename T >
struct AddConstVal<T volatile>
{
    using type = AddConstVal_t<T> volatile;
};

template< typename T >
struct AddConstVal<T []>
{
    using type = AddConstVal_t<T> [];
};

template< typename T, size_t N >
struct AddConstVal<T [N]>
{
    using type = AddConstVal_t<T> [N];
};
```